# Is a custom heuristic for A* of Tiles out of place - tiles out of place non-admissible?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I wanted to create a non-admissible heuristic, and what I've come up is tiles out of place - tiles out of place giving me a h(n) of 0 all the time. Have i made a non-admissible heuristic?

or what I've done is wrong and i create another heuristic and make a function which has a high h(n) value?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, I'd advice you to try and edit it to prevent ambiguities(see [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question on SO). In A*, we say that a heuristic is admissible if and only if it has the guarantee to be an under-estimation of the real distance. So a `h(n)= 0` all the time is an admissible heuristic if all your paths are guaranteed to have a positive distance (it actually makes A* behave exactly like Dijkstra's algorithm)

Comment: Sorry about that, thanks for your reply though @m.raynal

Comment: `tiles out of place - tiles out of place` is 0, period. Thus your question is equivalent to asking whether a heuristic of 0 is admissible, and it doesn't really make sense to think of this as `tiles out of place - tiles out of place` (this may make you think `tiles out of place` somehow influences the result, when it does not). Although a heuristic of 0 is not useful.

Comment: If you want to use a heuristic "tiles out of place + no. of moves made so far" can help.

Comment: @kiner_shah, the heuristic function will be only `tiles out of places`. The number of moves made so far is the cost of the partial solution, while the heuristic is responsible for under-estimating the number of moves left to do (at least \tiles out of place` moves left in any case). And yes, it's definitely the answer our OP was looking for.

Comment: @m.raynal, yeah you are right! :-)